# I am trying to extract password-protected ZIP files using zip4j jar file but i am getting error for following

Tags: java, zip, extract, password-protection, zip4j

I am very new to Java and I am trying to extract password-protected ZIP file using java and I have written code for the same but I am getting error for few methods such as isEncrypted(), fileHeaderList(), extractFile(),
I searched for few related posts/issues but did not find the exact resolution.
Can anyone of you help me in this issue

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
    import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;

    public class Extraction {
    public Extraction() {

            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:\\Users\\rajesh\\Desktop\\ZipFile\\file1.zip");

                //Error for isEncrypted() "The method isEncrypted() is undefined for the type ZipFile"
                if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                                        zipFile.setPassword("MYPASS!");
                }

                //The method getFileHeaders() is undefined for the type ZipFile
                List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();

                                for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderList.size(); i++) {
                    FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader)fileHeaderList.get(i);
        //The method extractFile(FileHeader, String) is undefined for the type ZipFile                              
zipFile.extractFile(fileHeader, "C:\\Users\\rajesh\\Desktop\\ZipFile");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please Try Again");
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Extraction();

        }

    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi Riaan, I have edited the post where I have given the error message within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported [java.util.zip.ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and are attempting to call methods on it which do not exist. You can find the ZipFile's API via the link I provided above. As you also imported `net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader` I guess you wanted to use a different zip library than the one found under `java.util.zip`. So in order to solve your problem you have to clean up your imports. You most likely need to delete the import statements for the package `java.util.zip` and need to import the appropriate classes from `net.lingala.zip4j.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `java.util.zip.ZipFile`, but it sounds like you want to use zip4j ZipFile class instead.  I'm not familiar with that library, but based on the docs online, I think you might want to import `net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile`.